# Can `newtxmath` be used with `amssymb` in PDFLaTeX?

Tags: newtxmath, amssymb

Using PDFLaTeX, this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
H
\end{document}
```

generates an error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\Bbbk' already defined.
```

Putting  `\usepackage{amssymb}` before `\usepackage{newtxmath}` does not work either but it gives a different error message:

```
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.--
```

Is there a way for PDFLaTeX to get Times New Roman in math and text, with `amssymb`?

Comment: `newtxmath` already provides the symbols of `amssymb`.

Answer (score 3):

The literal answer to what you asked is: yes, but you don’t want to. As egreg brought up in the comments, `newtxmath` defines every symbol that `amssymb` does, designed to match Times.  The `amssymb` symbols are designed to go with Computer Modern.

It will look ugly and all the typography nerds will turn up their glasses at you, but you *can* get Times New Roman in text and math, plus `amssymb`, with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{mathastext}
```

What you really want is `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` or

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0] % Or Times New Roman
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
```

Comment: Do other AMS packages have similar overlap with newtxtext?  If anyone wants me to, I can make that a new question.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking.  That’s a text font package, and there are some text fonts in `amsfonts`? Either `newtxtext` or `tgtermes` will cover the full repertoire of the OT1, T1 and TS1 encodings.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I mean, technically, there are some Cyrillic fonts in `amsfonts` that `newtxtext` doesn’t cover, I guess? You’d use `tempora` for those.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty You could load an OpenType Chinese font through `ctex` or `babel`.

Comment: The conflict in my file turns out to be between verbatim and  newtxtext.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Ah! I don’t think that’s supposed to set `\texttt`.

Comment: Updating the font maps solved the \texttt. problem.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Great!